# Getting a working chroot environment to boot with Grub2

Tags: linux, grub2

**Question**

I have a working chroot environment (inittab, fstab, init.d/rcS set up), a kernel, and grub2 installed. What more do I need to get my system working?

**Background/Specifics**

For educational purposes, I set out to put together a small linux environment that I can boot into and have a running shell.

Using Virtualbox I attached a virtual machine to two hard drives (with just one partition each). The first one has Debian installed, and on the second one I built a small chroot environment with Busybox, using [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4395). I also set up `inittab`, `fstab`, `init.d/rcS`, and most of the other filesystem related stuff as directed in the article, although I didn't do anything on the second page related to `genfromfs` and `syslinux` because I figured I wasn't making a bootable floppy.

To figure out how to get my chroot system to boot, I found [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275), and I ran `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb`. At the end it said it completed with no errors.

Then I created a new virtual machine, this time with the second hard drive as its only hard drive, and started it. It gave me a grub prompt, so then I [googled some more](http://www.justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?t=152790), and I typed in

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
linux /vmlinuz
boot
```

I had [read that initrd/initramfs is optional](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Initramfs), so I decided to overlook it for now. I built the linux kernel using `make defconfig` and `make` and copied over the bzImage under the x86 directory after the build.

However, soon I get a screen that hangs:

```
[ 0.74.. ] md: autorun ...
[ 0.74.. ] md: ... autorun DONE.
[ 0.74.. ] Root-NFS: no NFS server address
[ 0.74.. ] VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
[ 0.74.. ] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(2,0)
[ 0.74.. ] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the avaialbe partitions:
[ 0.74.. ] 0800  ... sda driver: sd
[ 0.74.. ] 0801 ... sda1 ...
[ 0.74.. ] 0b00 .. sr0 driver: sr ..
[ 0.74.. ] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
[ 0.74.. ] Pid: 1, comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.2.6 #1
[ 0.75.. ] Call Trae:
[ 0.75.. ]  [<c16..>] panic+0x57/0x157
[ 0.75.. ]  [<c18..>] mount_block_root+0x125/0x1a7
[ 0.75.. ]  [<c10..>] ? sys_mknod+0x27/0x30
.. a few more lines of call trace ...
```

I left some numbers out and the last few lines out because I had to type them in by hand, so if you need them let me know and I'll post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `root=` parameter in grub. The kernel is looking for the wrong root device, and so you get that 'unknown-block' error. I can see it properly detects your hard drive, so in grub you should use a line such as:

```
linux /vmlinux root=/dev/sda1
```